# Web API + jQuery AJAX DELETE request returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My ASP.NET WebAPI & MVC application is returning a 404 error when I request a PUT or DELETE.  It used to be returning a 405, but I resolved that by enabling CORS.  I have tried all sorts of different solutions (disabling WebDAV, change routes, put querystring in request), but none seem to have worked for me.  I'm hoping I just missed something extremely simple.  Here's relevant simplified code from each relevant file in my application:

jQuery AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/Signout?id=3",
    type: "DELETE",
    crossDomain: true,
});
```

SignoutController (GET and POST methods work from here just fine):

```
public void Delete([FromUri] int id)
{
    //Do things
}
```

WebApiConfig routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

//For another part of the application
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SaveSignout",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{signout}"
);
```

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
       path="*."
       verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
       modules="IsapiModule"
       scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
       preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
       responseBufferLimit="0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

RouteConfig.cs (saw this somewhere else on SO)

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

Fiddler DELETE request (simplified referer):

```
DELETE /api/Signout?id=45 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51301
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate (large base64 here)
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:51301
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:51301/Home/Controller/Id
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Fiddler response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B? (base64 of full local path to api/Signout)
Persistent-Auth: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAABDh+CIwTbjqQAAAAA=
Date: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 18:05:18 GMT
Content-Length: 4966
```

It's just a slew of various "solutions" I've come across that all apparently worked for those involved.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is url: "api/Signouts/54" works? I am not sure though

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me the same result.

Comment: Can you try using the [HttpDelete] and [HttpPut] annotations on the specific functions in your controller?

Comment: You have "Signout" controller, but in your jQuery you have "Signouts"...

Comment: @Marcin... You're right...   I'll have to fix it when I get back to it tomorrow.  Pretty sure this is going to be the solution though, thank you!

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Turns out I just added the "s" out of thin air while simplifying my code, and is sadly not the error.  The original line was `url: (apiBaseUrl + (uri || "/Signout")) + "?id=" + encodeURIComponent(signout_id)`.  I can confirm this is returning the right result by watching the XHR requests go through in Chrome dev tools, also in my post under the Fiddler DELETE request.

Comment: Also @CorstianBoerman, same result, thank you though.

Comment: if I use you sample with `url: "api/Signout?id=3"` I get `"DELETE http://localhost:64925/Home/api/Signout?id=3 404 (Not Found)"`

Comment: Yeah, unfortuatenly.  That's what I'm trying to fix.  Try using GET though, it works fine (for me).

Comment: Sorry, posted comment early! With `url: "/api/Signout?id=3"` it calls the method succesfully (note the `/` prefix). Your fiddle suggests this isn't the case but your ajax snippet is without the '/'.

Comment: Regrettably, my url is still correct.  I can verify it by copying it into my browser and hitting it with a GET, which successfully returns my `Get` action in the same controller.

Comment: Your `web.config` handler section tells `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit` to handle `DELETE` ... but are 32bit or Integrated appropriate? [[This answer refers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16241628/451944)]

Comment: ...It worked.  THAT WORKED!  Of course, a duplicate of my question answers my question.  I could have sworn I saw that question in my Google travels, though.  Please post your comment an an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default IIS does not serve DELETE requests: the `system.webServer` handlers defined in `Web.Config` can set how to process requests when your website's Application Pool has a "Managed pipeline mode" of Integrated (IIS7) or Classic (ISAPI 32 & 64 bit flavours). In your example, only ISAPI 64 bit is controlled. The following shows the other variations.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

*Reference:*

- [Related Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135100/asp-net-mvc4-web-api-controller-delete-request-404-error/16241628#16241628)
- [Extensionless URL Handler Background on MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4.aspx)
- [Background on Classic/ISAPI vs Integrated on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7)

Answer (score 3):

Richaux is correct, IIS does not serve DELETE, PUT and other requests by default. However, the `Web.config` part in that answer is showing how it was done in the MVC4 template. When creating a MVC5 Web API project from the MVC5 template you'll see the relevant part that registers the handler for all verbs:

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```